# send int array from ec2 servlet to s3 without creating local file

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My idea is to upload an int array from a Java servlet running on an AWS ec2 microinstance. As I understand it I would have to convert my int array to an java object file first and then upload the file into my bucket, but is there a way to do this "on the fly" without first creating a local file?
If I had to create a local file first, which pathname would it have?

Answer (score 0):

It will like this:

```
public void arrayToS3(String bucket, String pathInS3, JSONArray array) {
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    byte[] dataInMemory = array.toString().getBytes();
    s3client.putObject(bucket, pathInS3, new ByteArrayInputStream(dataInMemory), metadata);
}
```

Just convert anything into IntputStream. For example, the method arrayToS3 convert the JSONArray to String, and convert String to byte[]. Finally, wrapping byte[] to InputStream.

Everything is in memory. If your data is not very large, it is a simple way to do that. If you data is bigger than the memory set by JVM, out-of-memory will hit you.